# Android: avoiding tons of "dummy" one-fragment activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, tablet

I have several fragments that are used in combination in one activity on a tablet.

On a handset, however, one fragment is one activity.

So for the handset I have to create multiple XML files and multiple .java files just for the activitys that do not exist on a tablet.

Example:

for tablet I have:

```
activity A has fragments A,B,C
```

for handsets I have

```
activity A has fragment A, activity B has fragment B and activity C has fragment C
```

**For both tablets and handsets I use activity A, no problem**. But for handsets I have to create Activity B and C XML and java files, that contain barely nothing, just for them to host the fragments. To me that is not very elegant. I would rather want to launch fragment B and C automatically as activities and let them behave as activities, without needing to create tons of "dummy" files. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not replace the fragments in the activity itself instead of starting a new activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single activity in which you have a placeholder, such as `FrameLayout`, for your fragments. Then, you can [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) fragments as needed.

Something like

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mylayout, mMyFragment, "tag");
```

I believe, this is what they usually do when reacting on tabs presses in the ActionBar.